# Install only kernel updates having urgency>=medium

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade, kernel, updates

There are many kernel updates. As I have to build DKMS modules and copy the kernel and initrd to another location for netboot it takes very long and is very annoying.

By looking into `apt-get changlog linux-image-...` I can see the updates are mostly `urgency=low`.

Using `apt-get upgrade` the kenrel image is kept back. By using `apt-get dist-upgrade` it is included.

What I want is to only install updates that have `urgency>=medium`. Is this done by `apt-get upgrade`? Or do I have to change some configuration?

Comment: No, you really don't want to do that.

Comment: If you don't tell why, your comment is useless.

Comment: @Michael Because changelog urgency is practically meaningless in Ubuntu - most things don't ever change the urgency for any reason, so there's no real reason to try and track the urgency value.